# Multiple inheritance from classes sharing a parent

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Is it possible to inherit from multiple classes that share a parent?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2='a2'):
        self.a1=a1
        self.a2=a2
        
    def report(self):
        print('here are my attrs: ', self.a1, self.a2)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, *args, **kwargs):
        self.b=b
        A.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, c='c', **kwargs):
        self.c=c
        A.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, *args, d='d', **kwargs):
        self.d=d
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

If I try the above example I get:
`TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument`

I assume the issue arises due to `*args` and `**kwargs` from the shared parent class being duplicated when `super()` is resolving the MRO.

For context, I am trying to create a class that inherits methods and attributes from two other classes that share a parent.
 
If this is possible, how do you reconcile the different classes `__init__` constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the interpreter complains about `__init__` getting multiple values for argument `b` is because you're calling `B.__init__` from `D.__init__` with both a positional argument corresponding to `b` and a keyword argument of `b` in `**kwargs` with this statement:

```
super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

When you call a method through `super()`, `self` is already implicitly passed for you as the first argument to the method so your explicit argument `self` here actually becomes the next positional argument, `b`.

Your code would work by removing `self` from all calls to the `__init__` method of the parent. Also note that you should call `super().__init__` instead of `A.__init__` in both `B.__init__` and `C.__init__` to make them cooperatively pass the call to the next `__init__` method in the MRO:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2='a2'):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2

    def report(self):
        print('here are my attrs:', self.a1, self.a2)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        self.b = b
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, c='c', **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, *args, d='d', **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        self.d = d
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

D(a1=0, a2=1, b=2, c=3, d=4).report()
```

This outputs:

```
{'a1': 0, 'a2': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a1': 0, 'a2': 1, 'c': 3}
{'a1': 0, 'a2': 1}
here are my attrs: 0 1
```

Comment: thanks for catching my silly mistake in my toy example. So generally, inheriting from parent classes that share a parent is not an issue. Do the repeated `args`/`kwargs` just get 'eliminated' from the dictionary? I thought using `super()` is generally frowned upon in single inheritance and should only be used in multiple inheritance? In this example `super()` appears to make `args` and `kwargs` handling much cleaner.